# Subscribing to sensor data from model plugin

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm attempting to subscribe to a sensor's data from a **model** plugin. Simplified, my model plugin code looks like:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <iostream>

namespace gazebo
{
  class SensorRead : public ModelPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
    {
      // Store the pointer to the model
      this->model = _parent;
      
      std::cout << "Plugin loaded" << std::endl;
      std::string topicName = "~/my_model/my_link/my_sensor/imu";

        transport::NodePtr node(new transport::Node());
        node->Init("default");
      node->Subscribe(topicName, &SensorRead::OnUpdate, this);
    }

    // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate(ConstIMUPtr & /*msg*/)
    {
      std::cout << "An update!" << std::endl;
    }

    // Pointer to the model
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;
  };

  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(SensorRead)
}
```

The world code I've tested it with is equally simple, just a box, with a link, with an IMU sensor with an update rate of 5.

When I open a command prompt and do

```
gz topic -e "~/my_model/my_link/my_sensor/imu"
```

it starts spitting out IMU data 5 times per second as is to be expected. However, upon loading the model with the plugin, it outputs "Plugin loaded", and then... nothing. I've tried a wide array of namespaces, and have even verified in code that the topic name I use exists through `TopicManager::FindPublication()`. It seems like the topic is there, the events are there, but my model plugin is not allowed to have them.

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong, is what I'm trying to do not meant to be possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8327/subscribing-to-sensor-data-from-model-plugin/) by [Elte Hupkes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1155/elte-hupkes/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's probably because your Subscriber gets deleted at the end of the Load function. The `Subscribe` function returns a smart pointer, which will get deleted once it goes out of scope. The solution is to added a class member variable to hold the subscriber pointer:

```
this->mySubscriber = node->Subscribe(topicName, &SensorRead::OnUpdate, this);
...
private: transport::SubscriberPtr mySubscriber
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elte Hupkes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1155/elte-hupkes/) on 2015-03-25**:
Oh god, I feel like an idiot. I was so involved in finding a deeper problem that I forgot about C++ memory management. Yups, solves it, many thanks!